# How to customize marker styles and add numbers inside Folium markers

Tags: python, html, css, leaflet, folium

I saw an example to add numbers inside markers using `plugins.BeautifyIcon` here - [Folium markers with numbers inside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70896775/14045537).

But I need an alternate solution to add numbers without using `plugins.BeautifyIcon`.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster


m = folium.Map(location=[44, -73], zoom_start=5)

marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(m)


folium.Marker(
    location=[40.67, -73.94],
    popup="Add popup text here.",
    icon=folium.Icon(color="green", icon="", prefix='fa'),
).add_to(marker_cluster)

folium.Marker(
    location=[44.67, -73.94],
    popup="Add popup text here.",
    icon=folium.Icon(color="red", icon="", prefix='fa'),
).add_to(marker_cluster)

folium.Marker(
    location=[44.67, -71.94],
    popup="Add popup text here.",
    icon=folium.Icon(color="blue", icon="", prefix='fa'),
).add_to(marker_cluster)

m
```

[image]

Is it possible to customize the marker styles and add numbers inside like the below examples??

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### The following works for numbers from 0 to 9

As described in the [documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers), icon style can be picked from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons-glyphs) or, when using `prefix=fa`, also from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) (see example below)

```
m = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12, tiles="Stamen Terrain")

folium.Marker(
    location=[45.3288, -121.6625],
    popup="Mt. Hood Meadows",
    icon=folium.Icon(icon='1', prefix='fa'),  # choose your fontawesome icon style like this
).add_to(m)

folium.Marker(
    location=[45.3288, -121.7625],
    popup="Mt. Hood Meadows",
    icon=folium.Icon(icon='2', prefix='fa', color='red'),  # choose your fontawesome icon style like this
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image: map]

#### With your code snippet:

[image: map from your code]

Comment: `bootstrap icon style` didn't work for me. Blank marker

Comment: I understand your problem - It seems to be just a subset of the bootstrap icons, sorry for that. I corrected the bootstrap link and removed the non working example. Added the resulting map from the fontawesome example, hope that will help.

Comment: `folium.Icon(icon='2', prefix='fa', color='red')` still blank marker

Comment: If I use the code from your question and add the numbers to icon (eg icon="2") it shows the numbers. Which folium version do you use? I am with 0.14.0

Comment: yeah upgrading helps, i was on   folium-0.12.1.post1 version 
$ pip install folium --upgrade